# How to host my own project in IIS using InnoSetup 5.5.3?

Tags: c#, inno-setup

I created one sample Web application using C#, i want to host that web application in IIS using Inno setup.Output of that sample Web application is .dll,I searched in google i didn't get any steps to host the application in IIS using Innosetup,Can anyone tell me the steps and procedure for hosting the application in IIS using InnoSetup.